# Inject an EJB through the setter method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I'm defining a **Java EE** bean as follows:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class GreetingBean {

    private HelloBean helloBean;

    @Inject
    public void setHelloBean(HelloBean helloBean) {
        this.helloBean = helloBean;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And:

```
@Named
public class HelloBean {

    public HelloBean() { // ... }

    public HelloBean(String hello) { // ... }

}
```

1. Now, how can I **inject** the `GreetingBean` into another class by also setting an `HelloBean` instance for it?
2. Supposing that I've two different constructors for the `HelloBean` class (the one with an argument, for instance a `String`, the other without [*default*]), how can I properly inject either?

Comment: Why don't you just put @Inject on the helloBean attribute?

Comment: This isn't the problem of mine. Supposing that I've two different constructors for the HelloBean class (the one with an argument, for instance a String, the other without), how can I properly inject either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two different constructors, this is very different question from this that you are asking here. In this case the default constructor (without arguments) will be called when HelloBean gets instantiated.
To inject a bean instance using arguments you have to use a producer method which will instantiate HelloBean. More info can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html).

Comment: And how can I inject an HelloBean instance by using arguments?

Comment: Ok, I read about @producer and enum types, but something is still not clear. With the enums, I can choose from a set of concrete  implementations, but how can I pass an existent object as argument? - For instance, a concrete class needs a certain String into its constructor.

Comment: How about return new HelloBean("your string"); in the producer method?